# variable scope in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I defined a variable in Jenkinsfile and compute it inside a *node* block and I want to access/read its value inside another node block which is of my parallel logic. I got a `groovy.lang.Binding` error when I try to do so, is there a way I can expose one variable inside a node block to another node block?

Comment: What's your pipeline code?

Comment: Usually, you just have to declare the variable using `def var` on a higher scope.

Answer (score 3):

Initialise the variable outside the node scope

```
String var
node {
    var = "val"
}
node {
    echo(var)
}
```